# OSL tiles with rounded corners pattern

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, osl

There's a huge problem with an OSL script rework from [ngon-paradise.com](http://www.ngon-paradise.com/wiki/doku.php?id=prog:osl:osl-tiles-texture-en)

I try to make shading possible along the XYZ (3 dimensional coordinates instead of 2 dimensional.

I try to understand the core of the code but I missunderstand the things happen after definition of the simple square pattern.

As i realise the author define the base with a number of simple functions like: `asb(mod(x*scale,1) < width number/2` which create white pillars for tiles.

But then...

I would be grateful if you tell me what the hell is going on and how to add shading along Z axis.

I'll attach the code below. You can also download it from the link i posted before.

Thaks for your reply!

```
shader tiles_roundedcorners(
vector Coordinates = 0,
color Color1 = 1,
color Color2 = 0,
float Scale = 2.0,
float Joint = 0.05,
float Corners = 0.5,
int Rounded = 0,
output color Color = 0,
output float Fac =0,
output float Fac2 = 0,)
{
Color=Color2;
float width=1.-Joint;

float cu=mod(Coordinates[0]*Scale,1.);
float cv=mod(Coordinates[1]*Scale,1.);
float cz=mod(Coordinates[2]*Scale,1.);

float co=Corners*width; // corner is relative, co is absolute

if ( abs(0.5-cu)<(width/2.) & abs(0.5-cv)<(width/2.) ) 
{
    if ( abs(0.5-cu)<((width-co)/2.) | abs(0.5-cv)<((width-co)/2.) ) 
        { Color=Color1; }
    else
    {
        if ( Rounded==1 | Rounded==2 ) 
        {
            float djo=Joint/2.;
            float dco=co/2.;
            float pu, pv;

            if (cu<.5) 
            { 
                if (cv>.5) { cv=1.-cv; } 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                if (cv<.5) { cu=1.-cu; } 

                else 
                { 
                    cu=1.-cu; 
                    cv=1.-cv; 
                } 
            } // changing the coordinates is easier than to calculate the 4 corners separately

            if (Rounded==1) 
            { 
                pu=(cu-djo)/dco; 
                pv=(cv-djo)/dco; 

                if ( pu<(1.-pv) ) { Color=Color2; } 
                else { Color=Color1; } 
            }

            if (Rounded==2) 
            { 
                pu=(cu-djo-dco)/(-dco); 
                pv=(cv-djo-dco)/(-dco); 

                if ( acos(pu)<asin(pv) ) { Color=Color2; } 
                else { Color=Color1; } 
            }

        }

        else { Color=Color1; }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: humm... What's going on is: divide the original coordinates into tiles, and check if the uv coordinates at that tile fall into a corner or not, either checking if pu<pv for diagonal corners, or acos(pu)<asin(pv) for round corners. Now, this algorithm is for two dimensions, not three. If you want some thing that works with three dimentions you need to define a new algorithm (just trying to fit the Z into this won't work).

Comment: @Secrop, thanks for reply Can i ask you about usefull literature about algorithms for pattern generation? What should i read to improve my knowledge in this way?

Comment: Math books and Imagination. For textures and patterns, it all starts in the simple question: what color lies at this coordinates (x,y,z,u,v, etc)? And to get there we must be able to apply different transformations to those coordinates in order to create the final texture. In this particular case (3d bricks), you should start by defining the rules for placing the bricks in a 3d modular structure, that should fit well into the object... I can tell you that many tried it before, but in 3d it is very common for faces being totally inside a mortar zone, creating lots of strange artifacts.